# I want to get the index of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.clicker($ctrl.adherence.events[$index].id)">
   <scheduled-event

      event="event"
      ng-repeat="event in $ctrl.adherence.events">
   </scheduled-event>
```

In the code I want to use the index of ng-repeat to get the index of an array however my index value using $index is not retreiving this value.

Comment: Huh. You're using $index outside of the ng-repeat.

Comment: How could I use the index outside of the ng-repeat? If that's possible

Comment: To do what exactly? This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: That just makes no sense. just like you can't use `i` outside of a loop like `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { }`. `i`, just like $index, is the current iteration number. Before the loop, you're not iterating.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want to capture the $index and then fire your function based on that.
You can have an

```
ng-click="clickFunction($index)"
```

and then have that function do rest of the work.